# 3.5mm jack frequency response at low frequency (20Hz)

Tags: audio

I'm trying to drive a bass shaker at low frequencies, down to 20Hz, with an Arduino. Has anyone ever done something like this?

I found an audio amp that takes in 3.5mm aux, and I was hoping to get a 3.5mm jack to drive the amp from an Arduino. However, I can't find any technical specs on audio jacks so I am not sure if they support low frequencies. Are there any audio jacks with frequency response data available?

If not, are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: why the doubt? how did you get the idea that it would be a problem?

Comment: I have read that using aux to feed subwoofers is not recommended since many audio devices filter out low frequencies on aux outputs

Comment: but that is not a property of the jack, but a property of the amplifier. so the answer doesn't help you at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send DC (i.e. 0 Hz) through an audio jack, so I would not worry about its low-frequency response.

Comment: OP meant a jack input of the amplifier, not the connector itself